# iOS open contact in address book

Tags: ios, objective-c, abrecord

Since apple doesn't allow apps to directly call service methods using `NSURL`, I have a contact saved into the users addressbook which can call a service number. 
However, if I open the contact (using `ABUnknownPersonViewController`) I cannot call the service number.

My question: Is there some way I can switch to the address book app and show a contact there? I don't want to tell the user "Open your adress book and search for contact X".

Answer (score 0):

*To reply to your question:*
**No, there is no way to open separately the contact address book.**

*However:*
You can simply **take that number programmatically** and use it as you want (also call).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Performing a call requires me to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`, which doesn't allow the usage of * and #... so no, I cannot "call" it programmatically (without using private APIs). Or, did you have another suggestion in mind?

Comment: sorry can explain me better your problem about * and #?

Comment: From the [Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html):

`To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.`